# Drop down menu is not displaying sublists

Tags: html

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle"> Home </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/application/link1">
        <i class="fa {{aplcntStatusIcon}}" ></i> Link1
      </li>
       <li routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/application/link2">
        <i class="fa {{cpStatusIcon}}" aria-hidden="true"></i>Link2
       </li>
      <li routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/application/link-3">
         <i class="fa {{cpStatusIcon}}" aria-hidden="true"></i>Link3
      </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

When I am trying with the following code it is displaying 'Home' with the dropdown toggle but when I try to expand that, it is not displaying the subitems (Link1,Link 2,Link3).

Comment: add your running snippet along with css.

Answer (score 0):

You have not given the full code, so I am writing this answer assuming you are using Bootstrap 4

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <li class="dropdown">
    <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle"> Home </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/application/link1">
        <a href="#"><i class="fa {{aplcntStatusIcon}}" ></i> Link1</a>
      </li>
      <li routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/application/link2">
        <a href="#"><i class="fa {{cpStatusIcon}}" aria-hidden="true"></i>Link2</a>
      </li>
      <li routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/application/link-3">
        <a href="#"> <i class="fa {{cpStatusIcon}}" aria-hidden="true"></i>Link3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</body>

</html>
```

See if the above code solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using Bootstrap 4.x the script popper or the bootstrap bundle.

> Dropdowns are built on a third party library, Popper.js, which provides dynamic positioning and viewport detection. Be sure to include popper.min.js before Bootstrap’s JavaScript or use bootstrap.bundle.min.js / bootstrap.bundle.js which contains Popper.js. Popper.js isn’t used to position dropdowns in navbars though as dynamic positioning isn’t required.
>
> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/download/

Just add this to you head tag

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```